# Want to transfer clents project to her account - a specific project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to transfer a project from my firestore/Google cloud account to a clients account. I have gone through the google cloud platform but there's been no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this transfer in two different ways:

1. By transferring ownership: just add the new owner as [OWNER](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) to the project and to the [Billing Account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions).
2. By adding the project to your client organization: this only applies if your client do have a [Cloud Organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization). You can perfom this transfer only if your project does not belong to an organization ( GSUITE or Cloud Identity ) by following the document [Migrating Projects into an Organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing).

Comment: Alright thanks would do  just that.